# Setting today's date from lightning controller

Tags: lightning-recordeditform

I am new to salesforce lightning. I have a recordEditForm that I want to submit and before submit I want to make set field TODAY's date from the lightning component controller.I am not able to set the vale and throw error saying

> "{"message":"Value for field 'fieldName_Date__c' is not in ISO 8601
>   format, Value: 1/20/2019 11:19 AM, 
>       Runtime class: java.lang.String","detail":"","output":{},"error":{"type":"TRANSPORT_ERROR","details":{}}}"

**JavaScript controller**

```
onSubmitofRecordEditForm:function(component, event, helper)
{
    var recordEditFormList = component.find("newFormtoUpdate");
    // get all fields using event.getParam("fields") and set some field values in the backend onsubmit of the recordEditForm
    var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");
    var timezone = $A.get("$Locale.timezone");
    console.log('Time Zone Preference in Salesforce ORG :'+timezone);// Result::: Time Zone Preference in Salesforce ORG :America/New_York
    var mydate = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: timezone})
    console.log('Date Instance with Salesforce Locale timezone : '+mydate);// Result::: Date Instance with Salesforce Locale timezone : 1/20/2019, 11:14:03 AM
    var date = mydate.replace(/\,/, '');
    var lastModifiedDate = date.replace(/:[0-9]{2}\s/, ' ');
    console.log(lastModifiedDate); // Result ::: 1/20/2019 11:14 AM

    //salesforce field format is 1/20/2019 11:14 AM
    // not able to set the vale and throw error saying 
   /* {"message":"Value for field 'fieldName_Date__c' is not in ISO 8601 format, Value: 1/20/2019 11:19 AM, 
    Runtime class: java.lang.String","detail":"","output":{},"error":{"type":"TRANSPORT_ERROR","details":{}}}*/
            eventFields["fieldName_Date__c"] = lastModifiedDate; 

            // global function submit used to submit the recordEditForm
            recordEditFormList.submit(eventFields);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `new Date()` , the date you receive is already datetime of the browser ie its already in user locale( `$Locale.timezone` gives timezone of the user not of your org). You don't have to convert it anything.

Just, use [toISOString()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-date-toisostring-function/) on the date and it gives you Salesforce compatible format.

Thus your code will be minimal.

```
({
    onSubmitofRecordEditForm:function(component, event, helper){
        event.preventDefault(); 

        var recordEditFormList = component.find("newFormtoUpdate");
        // get all fields using event.getParam("fields") and set some field values in the backend onsubmit of the recordEditForm
        var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");

        //get current  time in ISO 8601 format
        var dateTimeNow = new Date().toISOString();
         console.log(dateTimeNow);
        eventFields['fieldName_Date__c'] = dateTimeNow;

    // global function submit used to submit the recordEditForm
    recordEditFormList.submit(eventFields);

    }
})
```

**UPDATE**: From Comments the solution was to use [Aura Localization service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_format_dates.htm) . The AuraLocalizationService JavaScript API provides methods for formatting and localizing dates.

```
({
        onSubmitofRecordEditForm:function(component, event, helper){
            event.preventDefault(); 

            var recordEditFormList = component.find("newFormtoUpdate");
            // get all fields using event.getParam("fields") and set some field values in the backend onsubmit of the recordEditForm
            var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");

            //get current  time in ISO 8601 format
            var dateTimeNow = $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ");
             console.log(dateTimeNow);
            eventFields['fieldName_Date__c'] = dateTimeNow;

        // global function submit used to submit the recordEditForm
        recordEditFormList.submit(eventFields);

        }
    })
```

Comment: By using you code I am getting this value dateTimeNow=====> 2019-01-21T01:44:48.645Z. where my date is 1/2082019 and time is 8.44 pm. In my saleforce org my time is 1/2082019 and time is 8.44 pm as well. 
 also I try with `var formatDate =     $A.localizationService.formatDate(dateTimeNow, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a"); ` but still it is throwing
alue for field 'fieldName_Date__c' is not in ISO 8601 format. 

my salesforce ORG date time field format is like this "1/20/2019 8:43 PM "

Comment: @demolightning Salesforce stores DateTime in format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ , I can see toISOString also returned in same format. Whats the issue exactly? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004680&type=1

Comment: It is working by changing the format `$A.localizationService.formatDateTime(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ");Thanks `

Comment: @demolightning whats the difference between output of `$A.localizationService.formatDateTime(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ");` and Op of `new Date().toISOString();`

Comment: @ Pranay Jaiswal                                                                                               
    `new Date().toISOString():::: Result###  2019-01-21T17:31:17.394Z` and `$A.localizationService.formatDateTime(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ")::: Result ####  2019-01-21T12:31:17-05:00.` Thanks all of you for the help.